Overwriting PDF File with Google Apps Scripts Causes Drive App to be unable to locate file
I have some code in Apps Script that saves a Google Sheet as a PDF.
I need to be able to update the PDF file when the form changes, without creating a new file and deleting the old one.
In theory, I think that what I have below should work. But when I make a call to the Advanced Drive Service's API, it says it cannot find the file, even though I am certain the File ID is correct and if call it in another context, e.g. to get its name, Drive seems to be able to find it.
    function replaceFile(theBlob, theFileId) 
{
  var oldFile = DriveApp.getFileById(theFileId);
  Logger.log(oldFile.getId());
  try
  {
    
    Drive.Files.update(
      {
        title: oldFile.getName(),
        mimeType: oldFile.getMimeType()
      },
      theFileId,
      theBlob,
      {
        convert: true, supportAllDrives: true
      }
    );
    
    Logger.log(Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName());
    Logger.log("Success!");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("PDF Updated With Success");
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    Logger.log(error);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(error);
    
  }

}
function test1 ()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pdfBlob = spreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
  replaceFile(pdfBlob,"1UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc");
}


Here is the error I get:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc.

Here is the link to the code I based mine on:
How can I overwrite the old file with app script when I save the file?
As far as I can tell what I have should work.
EDIT: here is my updated script, when I retreive the file with the Drive.Files.get() function it works, but with Drive.Files.update() it says the file is not found.
function replaceFile(theBlob, theFileId) 
{
  var oldFile = DriveApp.getFileById(theFileId);
  Logger.log(oldFile.getId());
  try
  {
    
    Drive.Files.update(
  { mimeType: oldFile.getMimeType() },
    theFileId,
    theBlob,
  { supportAllDrives: true }
  );
    
    Logger.log(Drive.Files.get(theFileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName());
    Logger.log("Success!");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("PDF Updated With Success");
    
    
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    Logger.log(error);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(error);
    
  }

}

function test1 ()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var pdfBlob = spreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf');
  replaceFile(pdfBlob,"1ZuftxjH8t6WVKR-sxHl98iywhRPDHnC-");
}


that is very unfortunate to hear, but thank you for the response

Are you sure this is specific to Google Drive as well as OS filesystems?

K J, I linked to this stack overflow post in my op. What bewilders me is why the Advanced Drive service can't find my pdf file even though I am certain the id is correct.

From your showing error message GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc., I guessed that the other part of your script worked.
And, from this error message, it seems that the file of file ID 11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc is not existing at Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName().
When I saw your showing script, your file ID of theFileId is as follows.
1UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc

But, at Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName(), you use the file ID as follows.
11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc

I guessed that in this case, the 1st character 1 is required to be removed. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.
If you want to use theFileId at Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName(), how about the following modification?
From:
Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()

To:
Drive.Files.get(theFileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()

or
Drive.Files.get('1UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()

Also, in order to retrieve the file name using Drive.Files.get of Drive API v3, you can also use Drive.Files.get(theFileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).name.
Note:

By the way, in the current stage, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, v3 is used as the default version. I'm not sure about your actual situation. But, if you are using Drive API v3, title: oldFile.getName(), is required to be name: oldFile.getName(),. But in your situation, the request body might be {mimeType: oldFile.getMimeType()}. Also, in the case of Drive API v3, convert: true does not exist in the query parameter. So, how about the following modification?
Drive.Files.update(
  { mimeType: oldFile.getMimeType() },
  theFileId,
  theBlob,
  { supportsAllDrives: true } // <--- Modified
);


By the way, if the latest Spreadsheet is not reflected, please add SpreadsheetApp.flush() just after the line of var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); and test it again.


Reference:

Method: files.update of Drive API v3


Thank you so much for your detailed response, I implemented the changes you prescribed but it still gives me the same error.

@Nate Bohn Thank you for replying. About I implemented the changes you prescribed but it still gives me the same error., if your error occurs at Logger.log(Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName());, it is considered that var oldFile = DriveApp.getFileById(theFileId); works. In that case, when you change it to Logger.log(Drive.Files.get(theFileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()), the same error doesn't occur. So, it is required to know your actual situation. So, can you provide your current script?

@Tainaike My mistake, I neglected to remove the Drive.Files.Update portion from my code to set the  Logger.log(Drive.Files.get('11UNOvk1qO5yR0Rs0xF3LrWaxYEgOxlRfc', {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()); portion. This does indeed work, and the error seems to happen in the block above that.

@Tainaike I put my updated script on the original post. Your correction to my Logger.log(Drive.Files.get(theFileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).getName()) line does work when the block above it is commented out. It seems that the update() function cannot recognize the file yet the get() function can.

@Nate Bohn Thank you for replying. About your new issue of but with Drive.Files.update() it says the file is not found., I have to apologize. When I saw my proposed answer, I noticed a modification point. So, I updated it. Please modify { supportAllDrives: true } to { supportsAllDrives: true }. And try it again.

ah I see that was my mistake. I implemented this change and my code now runs without error, however it appears that it does not actually change my PDF. Can you offer any insights into this? From what I understand of the Drive update function, this should in theory work.

@Nate Bohn Thank you for replying. From I implemented this change and my code now runs without error, I understand that your issue of your question was resolved. In this case, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

@Nate Bohn About your new issue however it appears that it does not actually change my PDF. Can you offer any insights into this? From what I understand of the Drive update function, this should in theory work., I would like to support you. In this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information? Because, when I tested the final script, I can confirm that the PDF file was updated. Also, your issue of this question was resolved. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

sure thing, I had not considered that these two problems ought to be separate questions but you are right.

@Nate Bohn Thank you for your response.
